# How to correctly draw other texture in fragment shader?

Tags: opengl, glsl, shader

How to correctly calculate uv coordinates for my sampler2D uniform?

E.g. i have main texture which has 1920x1080 resolution, i attached a shader to this texture, then passed other texture as sampler2D uniform which has 200x200 resolution.

Also, as i understand, i have to pass to a shader texture resolution and its normalized position. But i don't understand how to calculate uv coordinates for second texture.

```
uniform sampler2D u_render_texture;
uniform vec2 u_render_texture_pos;
uniform vec2 u_render_texture_size;
```

In main:

```
void main() {
   vec4 mainTextureCol = texture2D(u_texture, v_texCoord);
   vec4 renderTextureCol = texture2D(u_render_texture, what is here?);
   gl_FragColor = mainTextureCol + renderTextureCol;
}
```

Comment: Depends on how you want the texture to be positioned. Maybe draw a picture, to make the question easier to understand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to scale the texture coordinates according to the ratio of the texture sizes. If the unit of `u_render_texture_pos` is pixels and since the texture coordinates are in the range [0.0, 1.0], the offset must also be scaled.
Skip the color you got from `u_render_texture` if one of the coordinates is not in the range [0.0, 1.0]:

```c
uniform vec2 u_render_texture_pos;
uniform vec2 u_render_texture_size;
uniform vec2 u_texture_size;

void main()
{
    vec2 uv = v_texCoord * u_render_texture_size/u_texture_size 
              + u_render_texture_pos/u_texture_size; 

    vec4 mainTextureCol = texture2D(u_texture, v_texCoord);
    vec4 renderTextureCol = texture2D(u_render_texture, uv);

    vec4 finalColor = mainTextureCol;
    if (uv.x >= 0.0 && uv.x <= 1.0 && uv.y >= 0.0 && uv.y <= 1.0)
        finalColor += renderTextureCol;

    gl_FragColor = finalColor;
}
```

---

If you are using GLSL 1.30 or higher, you can use [`textureSize`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/textureSize.xhtml)  to determine the size of a texture:

```c
vec2 texture_size = textureSize(u_texture, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

OR

You can do that

```
mat2 scale(vec2 scale) {
    return mat2(scale.x, 0.0,
                0.0, scale.y);
}

void main() {
    vec2 scl = u_texture_size / u_render_texture_size;

    vec2 uv = (v_texCoord - vec2(0.5)) * scale(scl) + vec2(0.5);

    gl_FragColor = texture2D(u_texture, v_texCoord) + texture2D(u_render_texture, uv + u_render_texture_pos * scl);
}
```